# Problem: when trying to get byte[] from webservice take a lot of time and cpu usage

Tags: c#, .net, asmx

I have an old webservice on one server, which return pdf or doc file as byte[]. 
When I call it from an asp.net application on another server, it take a lot of cpu usage (I see it on the iis worker process). 
my questions are:
1. What causes it? and how can I Improve it? 
2. Will it be helpfull if I'll write it as wcf instead of webservice?
Thanks

Comment: We need more info here... what part of the process is causing the CPU load? Is it perhaps loading the file from its stored location? Is it the actual transfer? On initial response, web service should be lighter than a WCF service. I'd look at the loading of the file first, rather than the transfer... I'd bet the problem is there.

Comment: If you want to rewrite it, do it with `Web API`.